# Black & Scholes with stochastic interest rate

Tags: options, option-pricing, black-scholes, interest-rates, call

Consider the following model

$$\begin{cases}
dS_t=r_tS_tdt+\sigma S_tdW_t, \\
dr_t=adt+\eta dW_t\\
\end{cases}
$$
where $W$ is a Brownian motion and $\sigma, a ,b, \eta$ are positive constants.

I have to find a formula of the price of a call option:

$$E \left[ e^{-\int_0^T r_s ds}(S_T-K)^+ \right]. $$

Is it $$BS(S_0,K,-\frac{1}{T}\int_0^T r_s ds,T,\sigma) \quad ?$$

Can I obtain a more explicit formula?